# How to call a web-action from watson assistant dialog node?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, ibm-cloud-functions

I am trying to call a simple web-action from my dialog node. Both service and cloud space is hosted in London, still I am getting error that "Direct CloudFunctions calls are not supported on this platform".

I have created a simple skill and added 3 nodes to it, 1 is welcome node, second is test node in that I have added action of type web-action and created a webaction on cloud that returns a simple message. Below is the details for test node and action.

```
{
  "output": {
  "generic": [
  {
    "values": [
      {
        "text": "Hi how are you $message"
      }
    ],
    "response_type": "text",
    "selection_policy": "sequential"
  }
  ]
  },
 "actions": [
  {
  "name": "/namespace_dev/default/Call DB",
  "type": "web_action",
  "parameters": {
    "mob_num": "$MNum"
  },
  "credentials": "my cloud function creds",
  "result_variable": "message"
  }
  ]
  }
```

Below is the web-action code.

```
function main(params) {
return { message: 'Hello World' };
}
```

Node when test node is invoked the action should get executed but I am getting below error.

Dialog node error
Direct CloudFunctions calls are not supported on this platform

Can someone please suggest what mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, as stated in the [Actions Docs](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/dialog-actions.html#dialog-actions), the actions are accessible only in Germany and US South. However, this document differs based on the language you read in. In the German Version, which is my default, you might read this:

> Gegenwärtig können Sie eine Cloud Functions-Aktion über Watson Assistant-Instanzen aufrufen, die in den Regionen 'Vereinigte Staaten (Süden)' oder 'Deutschland' gehostet werden.

which translates (using Google) to this:

> Currently, you can invoke a Cloud Functions action through Watson Assistant instances hosted in the United States (South) or Germany regions.

If I switch to the [English Version](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/dialog-actions.html?locale=en#dialog-actions) of the Documentation, this information disappears.